# How do I deliver an item to end a quest?

Tags: the-secret-world

In The Secret World, you are given a quest to deliver an item (for example with Messsage In A Bottle, the last tier of the quest is to deliver the message to Norma Creed) but I can't work out how to do this.

I've tried talking to her, been through all of her conversation options and checked the quests she has to offer, how do I deliver the message?

Comment: Does Left clicking on her not work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've had difficulty triggering these quests sometimes as well - the trick seems to be clicking directly on the NPC in question - *not* their conversation bubble.

Comment: Confirmed that this is indeed the case.. I talked with a guy 4 times via those bubbles trying to turn in the quest and for some reason clicked on him the 5th time and it triggered.